# How to input text into steam guard prompt with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Been trying to use selenium to scrape steam-game related sites, but can't figure out how to get selenium to find the Steam Guard textbox and 'Enter' button. Instead I get the error that

```
NameError: name 'authbox' is not defined
```

Which means Selenium couldn't assign the authbox variable to a html element.

Code below, you'll need to input some valid steam login for the steam guard prompt to show up:

```
import time
import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Steam username
username = 'usernamehere'
# Steam password
password = 'passwordhere'
authcode = "FAKE"
delay = 1

#Using selenium to log in and then get the page
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://scrap.tf/buy/hats')
#Log into steam then proceed to new page
userbox = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
userbox.send_keys(username)
passbox = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
passbox.send_keys(password)
signin = browser.find_element_by_id("imageLogin")
#signin.click()
time.sleep(delay)
authbox.send_keys(authcode)
submitBtn = browser.find_element_by_class("auth_button leftbtn")
submitBtn.click()
```

TL;DR: How do I get selenium to recognize the steam guard prompt textbox after pressing "login"? If the code works correctly, it should input "FAKE" into the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Prophet, `authbox` is not defined so you cannnot do `send_keys` .
Instead you can try the below code  :

```
signin = browser.find_element_by_id("imageLogin")
signin.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#authcode"))).send_keys(authcode)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[text()='Submit']/..)[6]"))).click()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://scrap.tf/buy/hats")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "steamAccountName"))).send_keys('username')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "steamPassword"))).send_keys('password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "imageLogin"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "authcode"))).send_keys('12345')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[text()='Submit'])[6]"))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

However, it will enter `12345` and click on `submit`, but there will be some error from application side. Unfortunately we cannot do anything about that.  since it's expecting the security code which is sent to your registered mobile number.

Comment: Tried using this. I got the following error, help?  File "C:\Users\Tyler Wang\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: for which line first one  ?

Comment: The error is raised on the 2nd line, signin.click()

Comment: @Clockknight : Check out the above answer which in under updated 1 section.

Comment: Okay! Got it to enter the code. Not sure why, but the "wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "imageLogin"))).click()" raises an error, and I used the wrong ID in the original code, "twofactorcode_entry" is the correct ID for that textbox. The code cannot click the submit button for some reason. The error is raised on the line trying to click on the submit button. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I can say it's working pretty well at my end

Comment: For some reason, it isn't on my end. My solution is to import Keys, and have selenium find the authcode input box and input the enter key. 

Thanks a lot for the help, I was really stuck!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to send text to some element with command `authbox.send_keys(authcode)` but `authbox` is not defined.
This is what Python trying to say you.
You probably forgot to define that variable by finding the appropriate element or something like this.